# Creating actors with props that containt a self type

Tags: scala, akka, traits

I'm struggling with new method of creating actors that have a self type.

Let's assume I have an Actor

```
trait BarPolicy {
  val maxDrinksNumber:Int
}

trait ProductionPolicy extends BarPolicy {
  val maxDrinksNumber = 5
}

object FooActor { 
   def apply()  = new FooActor with ProductionPolicy 
}

class FooActor extends Actor {
   this: BarPolicy =>
}
```

Having that code I could write something like this:

```
context.actorOf(Props(FooActor()))
```

now this is deprecated and I just cannot find another way of doing this properly.

The "apply()" method should now look something like this according to what akka guys suggest:

```
def apply() : Props = Props(classOf[FooActor])
```

but where can I put the mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object FooActor { 
  private class ProductionFooActor extends FooActor with ProductionPolicy
  def apply() : Props = Props(classOf[ProductionFooActor])
}
```

Perhaps something like that?

Comment: That solution was something that dangled in my mind but I considered this something not very elegant. But maybe I should just cope with it if no other options are available.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
object FooActor { 
   def apply() : Props = Props(new FooActor with ProductionPolicy)
}

val actor = system.actorOf(FooActor())
```

Comment: This version is discourage by akka now:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Deprecated_Variants

Comment: The usage as shown here is not one of the problematic cases (which are when using this inside an Actor), we will update the docs to reflect this.